# Incorrect Stack Overflow icon

Tags: bug, chat, favicon, stack-exchange-button

When on https://chat.stackoverflow.com, the top bar uses the old UI and Stack Overflow's icon is incorrect.

EDIT: The same issue is on https://chat.stackexchange.com.

**https://chat.stackoverflow.com**:

[image: incorrect icon]

Related links:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362986/6754053

Comment: also in https://chat.stackexchange.com/ icon in the dropdown for https://stackexchange.com as well as meta.stackexchange.com is also incorrect

Comment: hmm.. cross site dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303895/incorrect-icon-assigned-when-navigating-from-chat

Comment: I don't see the wrong icon, but I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTIzg.png).

Comment: I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqCNZ.png). Wrong icons everywhere.

Comment: looks right to me.

Comment: There is no [freehand red circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138031/278654). I can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Incorrect for me in 3 different chromium based browsers.  The image url, `https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png`, does not contain any site information like other favicons on SE do.

Comment: @Zanon I've updated the image with a rectangle around the issue.

Comment: And this is why you should use a different filename/url when you change a cached css/images/javascript/etc

Comment: All looks fine to me, though I do see [wrong icons on the dev story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362903/wrong-site-icons-are-displaying-in-the-developer-story-story-and-traditional-v).

Answer (score -25):

Maybe you should clear your cache and cookies? Here is a helpful link. https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic
Good luck!

Comment: No, this is probably not a local caching issue, more likely to be a 'did the correct sprite sheet propagate to all CDN nodes yet?' issue.

Comment: I hate it when that happens!

Comment: It's the subtle difference between http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ and http://shouldiblamethespritesheetsnotpropagatingtoallcdnnodes.com

Comment: i bet it worked.

Comment: @heyguywhynotpy That didn't fix the problem. If you read the question carefully, you'll note this happens on specific parts of the SE network.

Comment: And here was me really hoping http://shouldiblamethespritesheetsnotpropagatingtoallcdnnodes.com was a website :/

Comment: And it's still a problem (on the [dev story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362903/1873567) at least) so there's no way it could be caching

Comment: ah heck sorry. i just wanted to help :(