# Wrong site icons are displaying in the Developer Story - Story and Traditional view

Tags: bug, status-completed, developer-story

Wrong site icons are displaying in the Developer Story - Story and Traditional view.

**Story view:**

> [image]

**Traditional view:**

> [image]

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362857/incorrect-stack-overflow-icon

Comment: This happened to me once on a mobile browser, but I thought it was just a caching issue or something because my internet connection was super bad that day and when I refreshed, they went back to normal, but I had the main stack exchange meta site's icon instead of Stack Overflow's.

Comment: Same issue here, with sites other than SO displayed correctly

Answer (score 10):

Looks like there's a bug in the CSS. For example, in the [CSS for meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Sites/stackoverflowmeta/primary.css) we have this line:

```
.favicon-stackoverflow {
    background-position: 0 -5868px;
}
```

However, the [developer story CSS](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css) is using this:

```
.favicon-stackoverflow {
    background-position: 0 -5832px;
}
```

If you change the position to match what we have here on Meta, it looks fine.

Comment: Issue still persists - any updates?