# Bio on Developer Story

Tags: support, developer-story

I was updating my developer story today, something I try to do semi-frequently, and noticed that when I accessed it via the public link the bio wasn't visible on the story.

Is this standard design? Why would I see the bio when viewing the profile signed in as my self but not seeing when visiting the shareable link? Is this a setting I can toggle somewhere?

- This screen shows what I see when I navigate to the "Developer Story" tab then click "Story View"
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1354251

[image: This screen shows what I see when I navigate to the "Developer Story" tab then click "Story View"]

- This screen shots what I see when I navigate to the shareable stackoverflow.com/story/username link.
- https://stackoverflow.com/story/kwandrews7

[image: This screen shots what I see when I navigate to the shareable stackoverflow.com/story/username link.]

Comment: can you add the link so that we can see if this behaves the same for others?

Comment: Going to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1354251 which is your public URL seems to show okay...?

Comment: @MattR updated the links above. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how this should work and why the two should be different? One URL is /users/story and the other is shorter /story/username.

Comment: @JonClements The bio doesn't show for me on that link. In fact, neither https://stackoverflow.com/story/kwandrews7 nor https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1354251 show the bio for me.

Comment: @Rob you are correct, my apologies. I just tried it in incognito, the bio doesn't show on either link. Is this a bug? Should it be reported somehow? Still seems like very odd behavior.

Comment: @Rob interesting... I can't see the bio at either link when incognito nor see the bio at /story when logged in... I can however see the bio at /users/story when logged in... I'd kind of expect it to *always* be shown (what's the point of writing it otherwise?) as there's not any options I can see in my own developer story settings to choose visibility for that element. Looks like someone from the jobs team will need to clarify what's going on here... (also - it's slightly odd that one has the SO icon followed by 6k and the other a generic cog icon followed by 6k...)

Comment: @JonClements Which cog do you mean? I see the SO icon and the SE icon

Comment: @Rob that's the SE icon is it? I thought that was the hamburger-speech-bubble thing... Whatever it is - they're different though :)

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, the hamburger is what I see: https://i.imgur.com/pb8C715.png

Comment: @Rob curious - I see what Kyle's posted in his second screenshot... *shrugs*

Comment: I see the second screenshot as well. He dun did broked the system.

Comment: The icon issue is the same as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362986/1663001) issue. Seems there's some work needed on the CSS files as SO!

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this issue with my Dev Story, it must be a setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The personal statement on the developer story does not appear to be public by default. Here's how to change that:

- Edit your "Personal statement" for your developer story.
- Find and uncheck the box with the option "Only show your personal statement to employers" as in the figure below.
- Check your profile. Here's mine, for example: [Matt P](https://stackoverflow.com/story/mattp_analystprogrammer)

[image]