# Incorrect Stack Overflow icon in developer story public link

Tags: bug, developer-story

The StackOverflow icon in Developer story is incorrect in the **shared URL** only. It is the correct icon in the developer story tab in the profile section.

## Screenshots

**Traditional View:**

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/cv/surajrao

**Story View**

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/story/surajrao

This is in both Chrome ( 64.0.3282.167(64 bit) ) and Firefox(58.0.2 (64-bit)) in Windows.

**Edit** Looks like same as [Wrong site icons are displaying in the Developer Story - Story and Traditional view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362903/wrong-site-icons-are-displaying-in-the-developer-story-story-and-traditional-v?rq=1) but not the SE icon. I see the StackApps icon.Let me know if need to close as a duplicate.

Comment: It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM2Pl.png) for me

Comment: @paper1111 odd.. I tried in both chrome and firefox.. consistently getting stackapps icon

Comment: Yes, seems like a small bug

Comment: @SurajRao The CSS file uses a different sprite map (and positioning) when you have a different pixel ratio. I can reproduce the results paper1111 has when I look at your developer story on my retina screen. However, when I move the window to my external monitor, I get the same result you have. Conclusion, the CSS (or the sprite itself) appears to be broken.

Comment: @g00glen00b that explains it.. seems like the sprite map has always caused issues..Remember seeing a bug regarding the site menu of StackExchange having wrong icons

Comment: I wonder why they have [one enormous image with all the icons](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite32.png) instead of one image for each icon.

Comment: Yup I got the same issue today. It is fine when I navigate to story from Dev Jobs but icons are all mucked up when I access it via public url.